# Reading text from a file has very slow performance, and I'd like to know why

Tags: c#

I'm not really a programmer as you'll see here, but it would be much appreciated to get some assistance to speed up this simple search:

I have some code that reads from a 10 megabyte text file and populates the relevant text to a textbox to help people at work search for part numbers.  It works on a background worker and it is populating a textbox very slow and I was wondering how I could speed it up?  Something like String.Join maybe?

```
 using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"T:\\PARTS\\DATABASE\\PARTS.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if ((backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
                else if (line.Contains(partNumbersText.Text))
                {
                    Action action = () => matchesText.Text += (line + Environment.NewLine).ToString();
                    matchesText.Invoke(action); // Or use BeginInvoke


                }

            }
        }
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: How large is the file, and how many things are being added to the text box?

Comment: My apologies, that is important I now realize:  10megs so it could easily be read to memory.  The file will never be much larger than that.

Comment: I have a feeling the slowness is in the network access of the file. I'd expect that with fast disk access, reading through a 10 MB text file and doing simple `Contains` on the lines should be ridiculously fast, to the point where you don't even need to bother with the background-worker stuff. Meaning if you can grab the text file contents and keep them in memory or at least in your local disk, problem solved.

Comment: 10MB is a **lot** of part numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing huge amounts of text to a textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427600/writing-huge-amounts-of-text-to-a-textbox)

Comment: Does _very slow_ have a value with some time units?

Comment: @JoeEnos I don't think it's the contains, it's the concatenation.  Run a c# program that concatenates 10MB of text into a string naively and watch it come to a screeching halt.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Good point - I guess it depends on how many results are matching and how big the results are. Naively concatenating even a few thousand moderately sized strings is still pretty trivial, but maybe a few tens of thousands or a bunch of big strings would slow it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a big file you are going to want to use a `StringBuilder` rather than concatenation because strings are immutable under the covers so concatenation over and over becomes very expensive.  Try something like this:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"T:\\PARTS\\DATABASE\\PARTS.txt"))
{
    StringBuilder strBlder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if ((backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else if (line.Contains(partNumbersText.Text))
        {
           strBlder.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
        }               
    }
    Action action = () => matchesText.Text = strBlder.ToString()
    matchesText.Invoke(action);
}
```

@Jim's comment, if you want to display the text as it comes you could print it out every x number of entries, so it gains some speed, but doesn't have to read the entire file before seeing anything:

```
const int ITERATIONS_PER_UI_UPDATE = 20;
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"T:\\PARTS\\DATABASE\\PARTS.txt"))
{
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder strBlder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if ((backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else if (line.Contains(partNumbersText.Text))
        {
           strBlder.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
        }   
        count++;
        if ((count % ITERATIONS_PER_UI_UPDATE) == 0))
        {
             Action action = () => matchesText.Text = strBlder.ToString()
             matchesText.Invoke(action);
        }     
    }
    Action action = () => matchesText.Text = strBlder.ToString()
    matchesText.Invoke(action);
}
```

Comment: This means he will have to read the whole file before getting to see results. Most searches don't work that way, they update as the data comes.

Comment: On the other hand, if we consider that 10mb is a small file and it actually speeds things up then who cares?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers.  This one was the easiest for me to compile.  I played with 20 updates vs 1000 etc, but the first code example you provided seemed to be faster if that makes sense?  I'll test again later.  The UI is a little unresponsive while I run it which I'm not sure how to fix, but the search results come fast enough it isn't a huge issue but id like to understand that too? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
matchesText.Invoke(action);
```

to this:

```
matchesText.BeginInvoke(action); //Not sure about the winforms syntax for this.
```

because the first one will have your Backgroundworker needlessly waiting for the UI to refresh, whereas the second one will not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't update the textbox every time you get a result. Use a StringBuilder to build your results object, and update the textbox only every so often. It's also a good idea to use the ReportProgress mechanism, like this:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"T:\\PARTS\\DATABASE\\PARTS.txt"))
{
    var results = new StringBuilder();
    var nextUpdate = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500);
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if ((backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }

        if (line.Contains(partNumbersText.Text))
        {
            results.AppendLine(line);
        }

        if (DateTime.Now > nextUpdate)
        {
            nextUpdate = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, results.ToString());

            //move this code to the ProgressChanged event
            //matchesText.Invoke(() => matchesText.Text = results.ToString()); // Or use 
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, that .Contains() check on 10Mb worth of disk data sounds expensive. You can speed it up some by keeping the file loaded in memory. 10Mb is nothing on a modern system, and as long as you're careful to keep from re-loading that data in a way that creates multiple entries on the .Net Large Object Heap, this will be by far the way to go.

Comment: Thanks but where do I move:  
            //matchesText.Invoke(() => matchesText.Text = results.ToString()); //  to?  If I leave it in place I get the cannot convert lambda expressions to type system.delegate...I'm not sure where the progress change event is?

Comment: You probably haven't created the ProgressChanged event yet. It's an event that BackgroundWorker can raise. Based on your error message you may need to leave the Action call as two separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

## You search through the file every time

It is the looking through the entire file, and the `contains` that is taking a long time, you should load the text up into objects that allow you to search on the part number, like a dictionary, but you did say that it will be too big, still you must be able to cache some of the numbers even doing something like this

```
//If there was a way to extract the parts number from each line I would do this
//but I don't know what the format is so I can't provide the code
//cache is a Dictionary>

if(!cache.ContainsKey(partsNumber.Text))
{

//then search through the file
cache.Add(partsNumber.Text,new List());

using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"T:\\PARTS\\DATABASE\\PARTS.txt"))
            {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if ((backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true))
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains(partNumbersText.Text))
                    {
                        cache[partNumbersText.Text].Add(line);
                        Action action = () => matchesText.Text += (line + Environment.NewLine).ToString();
                        matchesText.Invoke(action); // Or use BeginInvoke
                    }
                }
        }
}
else //this is where you will save time
{
   foreach(var line in cache[partNumbersText.Text])
   {
       cache[partNumbersText.Text].Add(line);
       Action action = () => matchesText.Text += (line + Environment.NewLine).ToString();
       matchesText.Invoke(action); // Or use BeginInvoke
   }
}
```

## This is only a small improvement

This isn't going to speed you up that much there are a few ways you could make your program a lot faster, the one that would make the most difference would be to make an index into the file you are searching.

### Make an Index

Keep track of where the part number is in the file, this isn't a quick fix. What you would do is keep the locations of the lines with associated part numbers in a separate file.