# Data Virtualization to handle text file

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I read this link :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization

to use Data Virtualization to read text file  :

In DemoCustomerProvider.cs , I changed :

```
 for( int i=startIndex; i<startIndex+count; i++ )
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer { Id = i + 1, Name = "Customer" + (i+1) };
            list.Add(customer);

        }
```

to :

```
  for( int i=startIndex; i<startIndex+count; i++ )
        {
            using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt"))
            {
                while (str.ReadLine() != null)
                {
                    string data=str.ReadLine();
                    Customer customer = new Customer { Id = i + 1, Name =data }   
                    list.Add(customer);

                }
            }
           }
```

The text size is 2 mb  but when start Data Virtualization, it uses 3 gig of memory!

I want to know how to use Data Virtualization to read text file ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading the whole text file, you are defeating the purpose of the Data Virtualization which is to lazy load only the visible parts of the data. To achieve this, you need a database or a file that has fixed record size and from which you can read subsets of data corresponding to the displayed parts in the UI. Please, reread the article carefully to understand what it takes. Moreover, avoid unnecessarily complexity if you are only dealing with 2MB worth of data. Do not use a sledgehammer to break a nut.

As a follow up to your comment, let me provide you with the following hints:
   You are reading your file repeatedly and getting count × number of records in the file.
   Your code executes each time you scroll. Take it from there and start modifying your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but 2 mb text file is the sample , i want to view larg text file about 1 gig. so can you explain more with code example to help me the right way? thanks in advanced. also i found this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427600/writing-huge-amounts-of-text-to-a-textbox , they mentioned about it but i need your help to solve the problem.