# Accelerate add text to a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, string, performance, textbox

I have code to set text of TexBox as

```
 textBox1.Text = s;
```

where **s** is a string that have more than 100,000 char, and it take long time to show text on textBox.

Anybody have solution to make it faster ?

Comment: Interesting question. Wait for solutions, :)

Comment: Textboxes are a bit slow for longer texts. Try using a Rich text box instead. That MIGHT speed it up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398037/is-there-way-to-speed-up-displaying-a-lot-of-text-in-a-winforms-textbox

Comment: Is this on Windows Forms or on XAML ?

Comment: @AymanDaoudi : WinForm

Comment: @MaRiO : than check my answer

Comment: @MaRiO: Seen this [Writing huge amounts of text to a textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427600/writing-huge-amounts-of-text-to-a-textbox)??

Answer (score 2):

To do that split the `s` string into many strings, and use the AppendText to add those subStrings, if you check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will see that :

The AppendText method enables the user to append text to the contents of a text control without using text concatenation, which, *can yield better performance* when many concatenations are required.

```
 public string s = "Put you terribly long string here";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //For responsiveness 
        textBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            //Here's your logic
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 1000)
            {
                //This if is just for security
                if (i+1000 > s.Length)
                {
                    //Here's your AppendText
                    textBox1.AppendText(s.Substring(i, s.Length-i));
                }
                else
                {
                    //And it's here as well
                    textBox1.AppendText(s.Substring(i, 1000));
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

I used the value 1000, you can use 1500 , 2000 , choose the one that gives better result.
Hope this helps.

**Update :**

AppendText is available for both WindowsForms and WPF, too bad can't find it on WindowsPhone and WinRT. so I think this solution may help you a lot

Comment: I dont think this is an option for WinForms, but for WPF, this is a great solution.

Comment: @Madushan : AppendText is availble in both, do you mean not an option PerfrmanceWise ?

Comment: I try this method but it still very very slow

Comment: My bad.. Sorry. It is available in both.

Comment: @MaRiO : Yes you are right, it is indeed slow, try my update now it is very fast, I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

break s in sub strings and when you pass first sub string to the text box it will appear after that it concatenate to the second and so on.
other way is that use loop to set the value

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length; i++)
{
   textBox1.Text += s[i];
 }
```

may these helps you